# maximising margin in svm

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

I have been thinking of this case as i was reading other questions and answers about SVM.

A question was raised about an SVM model having 1000 data points and 800 support vectors. The OP used a linear kernel. However, this is something that confuses me. If an SVM is supposed to maximise the margin between the 2 classes. How would the increase in number of support vectors feature in this calculations?

How to ensure that all the vectors are maximimum margin from each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to look at SVM from another point of view: It is minimizing [hinge loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_loss) with L2 regularization. This interpretation works better than maximize the margin interpretation when data is not linearly separable.

Increasing the regularization will increase number of the support vectors.

```
library(kernlab)
library(mlbench)
set.seed(0)
d=mlbench.2dnormals(100)
svp1 <- ksvm(d$x,d$classes,type="C-svc",kernel="polydot",C=0.1)
plot(svp1,data=d$x)
svp2 <- ksvm(d$x,d$classes,type="C-svc",kernel="polydot",C=10000)
plot(svp2,data=d$x)
```

[image]

In above simulation we are changing the regularization parameter $C$ to have different numbers of support vectors (shown in black in the plot) in a toy data set.

Comment: minimizing the hinge loss would require as many data points as needed? Can i have a more detailed explaination

Comment: @aceminer would the example help? [libsvm paper](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) section 2.1 will give you math details.

Comment: So just to confirm is this in high dimensional data? Or data in 2d. Not too good with r

Comment: @aceminer 2D data. 2 classes, ground truth label are circle and triangle.